# Application process of standalone APK failed with unknown reason

Tags: android, installation, apk

Application works well on real Android device under SDK Android, but as standalone signed APK - fails after installation. First, I receive message that installation finished. Trying to start application I receive message "Application removed". I have no idea and ask for help.

Here is my project:   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0ASfav4GTluVTFMajc2Q1F2MTg&usp=sharing

Here is logcat as 3 consеquent pictures:
       https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ASfav4GTluLWhXaHlCX2JtUU0/edit?usp=sharing
       ..................
       ..................
Sorry, I have unsufficient reputation to give more than 2 links :(

Also see, please, further messages.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need to post the logcat for anyone to be able to assist.

Comment: I have received logcat by "adb logcat *:E" command. Here are 3 pictures which have to be stuck together:          https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ASfav4GTluLWhXaHlCX2JtUU0/edit?usp=sharing   
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ASfav4GTluWUJWbzBuYnI1RkU/edit?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ASfav4GTluaHR4czNFaEtCRTg/edit?usp=sharing           Can anybody to say, what is the reason of installation's fail?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to provide enough information **in the body of the question itself** if you want people to help you.

Comment: I have developed, debugged an exported an Android application. Under Eclipse it works on real device well. At the installation of standalone APK file installation program failed. First, I receive message about normal end of installation process. When I start it, I receive message, that it was error in installation programm. Here is the AndroidManifest:

Comment: Here is my project:   https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0ASfav4GTluVTFMajc2Q1F2MTg&usp=sharing    I hope, this is enough. But I am ready to get any more information.

Comment: Here is my exported signed APK:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ASfav4GTluWXg0NW1yYUdHZ0k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions on stack overflow are meant to be useful for future viewers, not just you.  If you want help, you are going to have to provide the key information about the problem **within the body of the question itself, NOT AS EXTERNAL LINKS**.

Comment: There is an error in previous message: read "give" instead of "to get".

Comment: OK, Chris. I have edited original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. At first, once more the problem description: debugged application works well under SDK and fails in standalone mode.

*Problem's reason*. 
Open, please, AndroidManifest file in Android SDK (Eclipse). It has 5 bookmarks. Open, please, "Application" bookmark. It has text edit line "Permission" and rights - selection list. This selection list includes Android system permissions. Selection of any Permission of that list would be severe error. Application fails at installation; exactly - at the permissions check. Android gives no warning or error message in this case. Used permissions must be described only in Manifest xml file as a text.

I remove all linked files from GoogleDrive.